# Reading integers and finding minimum / maximum values

Tags: java, eclipse

Below you'll find an SSCCE.

I am trying to get a few integer's entered and see which is largest and smallest.

When I run/debug it only the first integer will get the code to show the `System.out.println()`.....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Comparison 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
        int a; //1st #
        int b; //2nd #
        int c; //3rd #
        int d; //4th #
        int e; //5th #
        int large = 0; //Largest #
        int small = 0; //Smallest #

        System.out.print( "Enter the first integer: ");
        a = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter the second integer: ");
        b = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter the third integer: ");
        c = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter the fourth integer: ");
        d = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter the fifth integer: ");
        e = input.nextInt();



        if ( a>b )
        {   large = a;

        if ( a<b )
            small = a;

        if ( a>c )
            large = a;

        if ( a<c )
            small = a;

        if ( a>d )
            large = a;

        if ( a<d )
            small = a;

        if ( a>e )
            large = a;

        if ( a<e )
            small = a;


        if ( b>a )

            large = b;

        if ( b<a )
            small = b;

        if ( b>c )
            large = b;

        if ( b<c )
            small = b;

        if ( b>d )
            large = b;

        if ( b<d )
            small = b;

        if ( b>e )
            large = b;

        if ( b<e )
            small = b;


        if ( c>b )

            large = c;

        if ( c<b )
            small = c;

        if ( c>a )
            large = c;

        if ( c<a )
            small = c;

        if ( c>d )
            large = c;

        if ( c<d )
            small = c;

        if ( c>e )
            large = c;

        if ( c<e )
            small = c;


        if ( d>b )

            large = d;

        if ( d<b )
            small = d;

        if ( d>c )
            large = d;

        if ( d<c )
            small = d;

        if ( d>a )
            large = d;

        if ( d<a )
            small = d;

        if ( d>e )
            large = d;

        if ( d<e )
            small = d;


        if ( e>b )

            large = e;

        if ( e<b )
            small = e;

        if ( e>c )
            large = e;

        if ( e<c )
            small = e;

        if ( e>d )
            large = e;

        if ( e<d )
            small = e;

        if ( e>a )
            large = e;

        if ( e<a )
            small = e;

        System.out.println(large + " is the largest number you have given.");
        System.out.println(small + " is the smallest number you have given.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It will be a lot easier to work out what's going on if you first recode this as a loop, take input until you get some signal from the user that all are done, tracking the highest and lowest for output when the user decides to stop entering data.  How would you expand this code if the user can input 1000 integers?  That's a lot of `if`s, when you only need two, if done with a loop and correct initial conditions on the highest and lowest tracking variables.  Maybe you could first ask the user for a count of entries N and then loop for i = 1 TO N taking the input values (here N = 5).

Comment: I think you are getting down votes because you haven't asked a clear question.  You are basically asking us to debug your code, which most people don't appreciate.

Comment: Also, you really should be using arrays instead of 5 variables.

Comment: I let out a small scream when I saw this code. If this is something you came up with yourself, wait until you learn about loops in Java. If a book told you to do this, burn it.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably due to the fact that you have:

```
 if ( a>b )
 {   large = a;
     ...
```

as your first `if`-statement, which you close in the end (presumably because the compiler told you that there was a `}` missing):

```
    System.out.println(large + " is the largest number you have given.");
    System.out.println(small + " is the smallest number you have given.");

    }  <------------
```

---

Here are two alternative solutions for you though:

```
....

large = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e));
small = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e));

....
```

---

and another using `TreeSet`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

TreeSet<Integer> integers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

System.out.print( "Enter the first integer: ");
integers.add(input.nextInt());

System.out.print( "Enter the second integer: ");
integers.add(input.nextInt());

System.out.print( "Enter the third integer: ");
integers.add(input.nextInt());

System.out.print( "Enter the fourth integer: ");
integers.add(input.nextInt());

System.out.print( "Enter the fifth integer: ");
integers.add(input.nextInt());

System.out.println(integers.last() + " is the largest number you have given.");
System.out.println(integers.first() + " is the smallest number you have given.");
```

A [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) can store elements and easily retrieve the largest and smallest elements.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not correct. The code will only be run if a > b:

```
if ( a>b )
    {   large = a;
```

This brace is only closed at after your System.out.println statements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, firstly, the your logic of assigning large and small isn't right.

You should assign a value to large/small , and cross check large/small against all the input variables.

Secondly, this would only work when `(a > b)` because the System.out.println() statements are in that block.

Answer (score 0):

aioobe's TreeSet solution is great! I upvoted too. For starters though, i think something along these lines would fit better...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Comparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int anum;
        int large = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //Largest #
        int small = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //Smallest #

        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the " + j + " integer: ");
            anum = input.nextInt();
            if (anum < small) {
                small = anum;
            }
            if (anum > large) {
                large = anum;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(large + " is the largest number you have given.");
        System.out.println(small + " is the smallest number you have given.");
    }
}
```